# Determine original coordinates of corner before rotation

Tags: rotation, trigonometry, transpose

I'm having a brain-freeze trying to calculate the original coordinates of the top, left corner of a rectangle before it was rotated.

Given that I know rectangle was rotated ***n*** degrees/radians, and I know the new **x** and **y** coordinates, how would I calculate the ***x*** and ***y*** (***?*** and ***?***) coordinates using trigonometry in JavaScript? I also know the  ***width*** and ***height*** of the rectangle. The axis of the rotation is central to the rectangle.

[image: example problem]

The rotated rectangle is in blue, the original is in green.

Answer (score 1):

you have to counter-rotate it around the pivot. (center of the rect)

```
//utils
function nr(v){ return +v || 0 }

class Point{
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = nr(x);
        this.y = nr(y);
    }

    add(pt){
        var a = this, b = Point.from(pt);
        return new Point(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
    }

    subtract(pt){
        var a = this, b = Point.from(pt);
        return new Point(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
    }

    rotate(radians, pivot){
        if(pivot){
            return this.subtract(pivot).rotate(radians).add(pivot);             
        }

        var r = nr(radians), c = Math.cos(r), s = Math.sin(r);
        return new Point(
            this.x * c - this.y * s,
            this.x * s + this.x * c
        );
        //return delta.matrixTransform( c, s, -s, c );
    }

    matrixTransform(a, b, c, d, tx, ty){
        return new Point(
            this.x * nr(a) + this.y * nr(c) + nr(tx),
            this.x * nr(b) + this.y * nr(d) + nr(ty)
        )
    }

    static from(pt){
        if(pt instanceof Point) return pt;
        return new Point(pt && pt.x, pt && pt.y);
    }
}
```

and the computation:

```
var RAD = Math.PI/180, DEG = 180/Math.PI;

var knownPoint = new Point(100, 100);
var angle = 30*RAD;

var unrotatedRect = { width: 150, height: 100 };
//the pivot to (counter-)rotate your known point
//if you know this point, you don't have to compute it
var pivot = new Point(unrotatedRect.width/2, unrotatedRect.height/2)
    .rotate(angle)
    .add(knownPoint);

console.log(knownPoint.rotate(-angle, pivot));
```

Answer (score 0):

The original *X* is exactly as far from the axis as the **transposed** ("rotated") *Y* is, and vice versa, the original *Y* is as far as the transposed *X* is from the axis.

So:

> *origX* = *axisX* - (*axisY* - *transY*)
>     *origY* = *axisY* - (*axisX* - *transX*)

Comment: Apologies, it's a little early in the morning for me. Can I have the transposition formula? i.e how do I get `transX` and `transY` from the information I have?

Comment: @shennan *transX,Y* = "*newX,Y*"

Comment: The `origY` doesn't seem to be calculated correctly with this. Given a rectangle with `var width = 200, height = 100, axisX = 275, axisY = 200, transX = 325, transY = 47.7;` the resulting `origY` is `250` where it should surely be `150`? The `origX` seems correct at `122.69`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reverse the sign:  transY - axisY

Comment: Surely you mean reverse the sign `transX - axisX`?

Comment: Well the pattern is not consistent through different rotations, so no I don't. If I rotate -90deg it is correct. -270deg and it is wrong again. All rotations should produce the same result for the aforementioned axis/width/height. That is `origX = 122.69` and `origY = 150`. I don't see how you could possibly determine the original ***x*** and ***y*** positions of a rotated rectangle without using the new angle in the calculations.